# Revolution slider with video: Connection closed

Tags: revolution-slider, payara

We have a JSF application running on Payara server (5.182) which incorporates web pages with Revolution Slider (5.4.6.4).

Some of the slides are setup as video backgrounds, and for the most part it's working exactly as designed, however, we do intermittently see the following WARNING trace in the server logs:

```
[2018-08-08T09:15:20.329-0400] [Payara 5.182] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=31 _ThreadName=http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(5)] [timeMillis: 1533734120329] [levelValue: 900] [[
  StandardWrapperValve[default]: Servlet.service() for servlet default threw exception
java.io.IOException: Connection closed
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.asyncqueue.TaskQueue.onClose(TaskQueue.java:307)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter.onClose(AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter.java:477)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.closeConnection(TCPNIOTransport.java:388)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.NIOConnection.doClose(NIOConnection.java:642)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.NIOConnection$6.run(NIOConnection.java:608)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.DefaultSelectorHandler.execute(DefaultSelectorHandler.java:213)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.NIOConnection.terminate0(NIOConnection.java:602)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOConnection.terminate0(TCPNIOConnection.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOAsyncQueueWriter.writeCompositeRecord(TCPNIOAsyncQueueWriter.java:173)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOAsyncQueueWriter.write0(TCPNIOAsyncQueueWriter.java:68)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter.processAsync(AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter.java:320)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:84)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:53)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:524)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:89)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:94)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.executeIoEvent(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:80)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.executeIoEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:66)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.iterateKeyEvents(SelectorRunner.java:391)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.iterateKeys(SelectorRunner.java:360)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.doSelect(SelectorRunner.java:324)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.run(SelectorRunner.java:255)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:569)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:549)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(Unknown Source)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOUtils.flushByteBuffer(TCPNIOUtils.java:125)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOAsyncQueueWriter.writeCompositeRecord(TCPNIOAsyncQueueWriter.java:165)
    ... 16 more
```

We are assuming that this occurs when the entire video has not yet been loaded and then the slider rotates to the next slide, but that's really just a guess.  We have tried modifying the logger settings on the server just to eliminate the warning, but that doesn't solve the root problem.

Does anyone have any insight as to what we might change either in the code of the slider page or on the server console to remedy this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi, first of all, this question is as it stands now not jsf related (no jsf class in the stacktrace nor in the code you provided), not java-ee (way to broad) and most likely a similar error would occur on wildfly, glassfish, tomcat or the likes. And I think the only way you can fully prevent this error is to make the slider not slide if the running video is not finished AND prevent the user to use the back and forward buttons on the browser AND to prevent the user to close the browser. Last ones are hard to solve, first one is

Comment: @Kukeltje thank you for taking the time to reply.  As this is my first post, I apologize for the extra tags.  Even though they were broad, I thought it might be helpful to include them, but I've removed them.  I totally agree with your response, but with the popularity of these sliders, I'm still surprised there isn't a way to address this warning message when the application is running within a servlet container.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says: "An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine" the problem isn't caused by anything running in the JVM. It's not related to Payara or even Java at all.

You should check what's causing that the connection was aborted. I assume some firewall configuration, network control software or worst case a virus.

Comment: I appreciate your comment. This is one of those issues that is difficult to explain since a lot of things are tied together.  I agree that this isn't a Java or Payara issue per se.  If anything,  it's more of a Javascript/AJAX issue under the covers in the revolution slider code.  I was simply describing the architecture of the application.  I believe the connection is being aborted during the script execution due to the fact that the video (mp4) file request isn't complete and the slider is moving on, and the servlet container is warning me.  Again, this isn't an error so much.